# Java how to link notification and polling

Tags: java

I'm looking the best solution to link a parameter which is shared by two interface: rest and soap.

A function named "isNotification()" is polled by a web service and in parallel another web service notified the application through the soap interface by calling "notified()" function.

I'm looking for the best way to implement this, and lock the soap request until the rest request has collected the notified information.

Comment: Your question is very broad and it is unknown what system/framework you are using. Basically you are looking for java thread synchronization and there are several solutions and approaches for this. Please [edit] your question to ask about a specific problem, see [ask].

Comment: What do you mean by _lock the soap request_?  From the description, it sounds like a producer (soap) / consumer (rest) set up, with a queue in the middle to decouple the producer and consumer processes.

Comment: By lock the soap request i mean not send the soap response until the response of the rest request.